# Create and open Adobe Illustrator document from PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create an Illustrator file from PowerShell. I can create a new .ai file, but Illustrator can't open it.

Here is what I tried:

```bash
PS C:\Users\my.name> Invoke-Item "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator 2023\Adobe Illustrator 2023.lnk"
PS C:\Users\my.name> New-Item -Path "C:\Users\my.name\Documents\scripting\testfile.ai"
```

When I go to the file location, the file exists as a .ai document, but I get this error when I try to open it:

[Can't open the illustration. The file may be read only, or the file is in use by another application, or you do not have the required permissions. Please save the document with a different name, or in a different folder or directory.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARa5p.png)

Anyone know why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently your first command just starts illustrator, nothing else. The second just creates an empty file.

You'll probably want to create a new .ai file **manually** somewhere as a template, then copy it as needed:

```bash
Copy-Item "C:\folder\template.ai" "C:\folder\testfile.ai"
```

Once you have a new testfile, then you can open it in illustrator like so, as long as your default program for ai files is correct:

```bash
Start-Process "C:\folder\testfile.ai"
```